# Why python is giving out an error on this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's the link to [Wikibooks Python tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Variables_and_Strings). I was practising the "Combining Numbers and Strings" given on that page. The first code is certain to produce an error (it is written there) but the second code is also producing an error:

```
print ("Please give me a number:",) 
response = raw_input()   
number = int(response) 
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
number = int(response) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I can't seem to find out how to fix it.
I am using Python 3.3.0 and I know it is input() and not raw_input(). 
Please help.

Comment: 1) when asking for help on an error, always include the actual error.  We can't read your mind.  2) Make sure you are using python 2 if the code was written for python 2.

Comment: @NedBatchelder I made the edits. Now tell me please.

Comment: @PreetikaSharma read Ashwinis answer - of course the code fails if you don't enter a valid number. What the hell did you expect to happen? Oh and congratulations, you definitely win the "worst question of today" award...

Comment: @l4mpi Now if I type what Ashwini wrote, it happnes like this:
 try:
 response = input()
 print int(response), "valid input"
 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @PreetikaSharma you shouldn't use offensive language here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are combining a string and an integer.

```
print ("Please give me a number: ")
number = input()

plusTen = int(number) + 10
print ("If we add 10 to your number, we get " + str(plusTen))
```

Is the correct code.

Comment: Now this error:    
    >>>print("Please give me a number: ")
    Please give me a number:
    >>> number = input()

    >>> plusTen = int(number) + 10
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
        plusTen = int(number) + 10
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Hey, the error is coming out saying that can't convert int to a str implicitly. That means, if I try do: plusTen = int(number) + 10 then the error comes out because 10 is int and can't be converted into a str. Now how to do that?

Comment: Thank you dude. This was the right answer. Finally I figured it out. Thanks dude thank you.

Comment: No problem, it's similar to something I had when I was beginning to program.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an empty string to `int()`, that is why it is throwing the `ValueError`:

```
>>> int('')

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

You can use a `try-except` block to get around that.

```
>>> try:
    response = input("enter a number: ") 
    print (int(response),"valid input")
except ValueError:    
    print ("invalid input")
   .....:     
enter a number: 123               #input
123 valid input

>>> try:
    response = input("enter a number: ") 
    print (int(response),"valid input")
except ValueError:    
    print ("invalid input")
   .....:     
enter a number: abc                        #input
invalid input
```

Comment: This is happening:
>>> try:
 response = input()
 print int(response), "valid input"
 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @PreetikaSharma use `print (int(response), "valid input" )`, in python 3.x `print()` is a  function.

Comment: @PreetikaSharma I am still learning, it's a slow process. http://norvig.com/21-days.html.

Comment: My god. 10 years. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I am sorry but it still gets out an error. Now if you can help me with how to convert an int to str. that would be rather great